# What is AFS Kerberos used for? Can I safely remove it?

Tags: 14.04, networking, kerberos

I'm trying to eliminate unused services that listen on open ports. My hope is to better secure my system.

After running nmap I found only one service listening on port 7004 that I wasn't already aware of.

```
sudo nmap 192.168.1.251
7004/tcp open  afs3-kaserver
```

After reading a little about this service on a few sites, I still don't know if this is required for something important. I do allow ssh logins from my LAN only.

Edit:
Here is the related service config from /etc/services file:

```
afs3-fileserver 7000/tcp        bbs             # file server itself
afs3-fileserver 7000/udp        bbs
afs3-callback   7001/tcp                        # callbacks to cache managers
afs3-callback   7001/udp
afs3-prserver   7002/tcp                        # users & groups database
afs3-prserver   7002/udp
afs3-vlserver   7003/tcp                        # volume location database
afs3-vlserver   7003/udp
afs3-kaserver   7004/tcp                        # AFS/Kerberos authentication
afs3-kaserver   7004/udp
afs3-volser     7005/tcp                        # volume managment server
afs3-volser     7005/udp
afs3-errors     7006/tcp                        # error interpretation service
afs3-errors     7006/udp
afs3-bos        7007/tcp                        # basic overseer process
afs3-bos        7007/udp
afs3-update     7008/tcp                        # server-to-server updater
afs3-update     7008/udp
afs3-rmtsys     7009/tcp                        # remote cache manager service
afs3-rmtsys     7009/udp
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`AFS` is the "Andrew File System" from CMU, which uses Kerberos as its identification/authentication scheme.

If none of the above makes sense to you, you can probably live without it.

Find out which package is responsible for installing it via `sudo dpkg -S afs3-kaserver` and `sudo apt-get uninstall` that package.

If `dpkg -S afs3-kaserver` returns `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *afs3-kaserver*`, it was not installed via the package manager (`apt`. `dpkg`, `synaptic`, etc), and you will have to track down how it gets started (`/etc/init/`, `/etc/init.d/`).

To be really paranoid, wrap the commands to disable and re-enable the service in `bash` scripts, and use `at` to schedule the disable for `now+2min` and the re-enable for `now+12min` to give you a 10 minute test window before things are put back to normal. Who knows, you might have something important using `afs3-kerberos`

Comment: The dpkg command returned "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *afs3-kaserver*" as you said it might. I wonder if this is part of the Ubuntu update notification mechanism?

Comment: Probably not, no afs3-kaserver on my  4 Ubuntu 14.04.03 systems

Comment: +1 for your help. I'll continue to figure out why it is installed. Very likely a result of something I installed.